# How to use grep and cut together?

Tags: grep, cut, database

Lets say I'm doing a database for fruits.
Using a text file for it, inside contains, in this format,

```
(Fruit:Quantity:Cost)
Apple:10:1
Orange:20:2
Pears:10:3
Banana:20:4

10 Apples at $1 each.
20 Oranges at $2 each.
10 Pears at $3 each.
20 Bananas at $4 each.
```

My simple script goes like this:

```
echo "Enter fruit to find"
read fruit

echo "Enter quantity to find"
read count

echo "Enter cost to find"
read cost

grep $fruit FruitDB.txt
```

---

It will display the fruits in the database.

But how do i use grep and cut together to find just by the quantity or the cost. In the quantity count area, let's say i enter 20, it will display the Oranges and Banana. Or when i enter count and cost, it will display just those that meet the conditions.

Comment: Usually such cases would be handled with `awk`. Is `grep` a requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `cut` at all, just bare `grep` is enough in the form:

```
grep "^$fruit:$count:$cost$" FruitDB.txt
```

Remove any variable you don't want to grep at the time (but leave separators `:`, and begining and end of line signs `^` and `$` (for edge variables)).

For example to grep those with `count=20`:

```
$ grep ":$count:" FruitDB.txt
Orange:20:2
Banana:20:4
```

grep those with `count=20` and `cost=2`:

```
$ grep ":$count:$cost$" FruitDB.txt
Orange:20:2
```

Comment: You may prefer `grep -xFe "$fruit:$count:$cost"` in case those variables contain regexp operators (for instance `.` in `$cost`).